# Latex \newcommand with python code inside

Tags: macros, packages, python

I'm extremely new to Latex. I'm using [python](https://github.com/brotchie/python-sty) package to insert graphics in a loop. What I can not understand is how I can transform this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{python}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{python}
import os
print r"\fbox{bla bla}"
\end{python}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

into something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{python}

\newcommand\insPython[1]{
{
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{python}
import os
print r"#1"
\end{python}
\end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

\insPython{bla bla}

\end{document}
```

The second version does not work. Is there any way to wrap a Python code into a Latex command?

Comment: It sounds like: [Why doesn't verbatim work within ...?](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=verbwithin)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way would be to use `pythontex` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\newcommand\insPython[1]{
\begin{figure}
\centering
\pyc{import os;
print (r"#1")}
\end{figure}
}

\begin{document}
\insPython{bla bla}

\end{document}
```

You need to run `pdflatex` then `pythontex` (or `pythontex.exe`) and `pdflatex` again.

Somehow I needed to use Python 3 syntax, but maybe because I have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed on my system.

Comment: Regarding Python 3 syntax:  `pythontex` imports everything from `__future__` except for `unicode_literals` by default.  This can be modified using the `pyfuture` package option.

Comment: @Tahtisilma, thank you a lot! Your solution worked fine for me.